# XML - Markup following root element must be well-formed

Tags: xml, markup, root-element

I keep getting errors with my xml file when trying to run a build... this is the error:

> lineNumber: 68; columnNumber: 12; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

Here's the code:

```
  <module name="Checker">
 <module name="LineLength">
    <property name="max" value="150"/>
</module>

   <module name="BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter">
        <property name="fileNamePattern" value="module\-info\.java$"/>
    </module>
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java, properties, xml"/>

    <!-- General file conventions -->
    <module name="NewlineAtEndOfFile">
        <property name="lineSeparator" value="lf_cr_crlf" />
    </module>
    <module name="FileTabCharacter"/>
    <module name="RegexpSingleline">
        <property name="format" value="\s+$"/>
        <property name="minimum" value="0"/>
        <property name="maximum" value="0"/>
        <property name="message" value="Line has trailing spaces."/>
    </module>

    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <!-- Naming conventions -->
        <module name="ConstantName"/>
        <module name="LocalFinalVariableName"/>
        <module name="LocalVariableName"/>
        <module name="MemberName"/>
        <module name="MethodName"/>
        <module name="PackageName"/>
        <module name="ParameterName"/>
        <module name="StaticVariableName"/>
        <module name="TypeName"/>
     </module>

        <!-- Checks for imports -->
      <module name="AvoidStarImport"/>
          <property name="excludes" value="java.io,java.net,java.lang.Math"/>
     </module>
          <module name="IllegalImport"/>
          <module name="RedundantImport"/>
          <module name="UnusedImports"/>
             <property name="processJavadoc" value="false"/>
     </module>

        <!-- Checks for Size Violations -->
        <module name="MethodLength"/>
        <module name="ParameterNumber"/>

        <!-- Checks for whitespace -->
            <module name="EmptyForIteratorPad"/>
        <module name="GenericWhitespace"/>
        <module name="MethodParamPad"/>
        <module name="NoWhitespaceAfter"/>
        <module name="NoWhitespaceBefore"/>
        <module name="OperatorWrap"/>
        <module name="SeparatorWrap">
            <property name="tokens"
                      value="COMMA,LPAREN,RPAREN,RBRACK,ARRAY_DECLARATOR"/>
            <property name="option" value="eol"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SeparatorWrap">
            <property name="tokens" value="DOT,METHOD_REF,ELLIPSIS,AT"/>
            <property name="option" value="nl"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ParenPad"/>
        <module name="TypecastParenPad"/>
        <module name="WhitespaceAfter"/>
        <module name="WhitespaceAround"/>
        <module name="SingleSpaceSeparator"/>

        <!-- Modifier Checks -->
            <module name="ModifierOrder"/>
        <module name="RedundantModifier"/>

        <!-- Checks for blocks. You know, those {}'s -->
            <module name="AvoidNestedBlocks"/>
        <module name="EmptyBlock"/>
        <module name="LeftCurly"/>
        <module name="NeedBraces"/>
        <module name="RightCurly"/>

        <!-- Checks for common coding problems -->
            <module name="EmptyStatement"/>
        <module name="EqualsHashCode"/>
        <module name="IllegalInstantiation"/>
        <module name="InnerAssignment"/>
        <module name="MultipleVariableDeclarations"/>
        <module name="SimplifyBooleanExpression"/>
        <module name="SimplifyBooleanReturn"/>

        <!-- Checks for class design -->
            <module name="DesignForExtension"/>
        <module name="FinalClass"/>
        <module name="HideUtilityClassConstructor"/>
        <module name="InterfaceIsType"/>
        <module name="VisibilityModifier"/>

        <!-- Miscellaneous other checks -->
            <module name="ArrayTypeStyle"/>
        <module name="UpperEll"/>
        <module name="Indentation">
            <property name="caseIndent" value="0"/>
            <property name="lineWrappingIndentation" value="8"/>
        </module>

        <!-- Checks for annotations -->
            <module name="MissingOverride"/>
        </module>
```

The line that's having problems is:

```
         <module name="IllegalImport"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated! I have tried adding an end tag name but to no avail.

Comment: Is `<module name="UnusedImports"/>` supposed to be `<module name="UnusedImports">` without the slash at the end, so it contains the following `<property name="processJavadoc" value="false"/>` tag?

Comment: @Progman yes thank you! I fixed that however I'm still getting the error.

Comment: You have several instances of that error.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to remove the self-closing `/` from:

```xml
<module name="AvoidStarImport"/>
```

and

```xml
<module name="UnusedImports"/>
```

Comment: Did you mean "...you need to _remove_ the self-closing..."

Comment: @JimGarrison - (facepalm) yes I somehow omitted the "to remove". Thanks!!

Comment: Happens to me too... my brain is too far ahead of my fingers :-)